# Unable to connect to k8s cluster using master/worker IP

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, calico, kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to install a Kubernetes cluster with one master node and two worker nodes.

I acquired 3 VMs for this purpose running on Ubuntu 21.10. In the master node, I installed `kubeadm:1.21.4`, `kubectl:1.21.4`, `kubelet:1.21.4` and `docker-ce:20.4`.

I followed [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-with-kubeadm/) to install the cluster. The only difference was in my init command where I did not mention the `--control-plane-endpoint`. I used calico CNI `v3.19.1` and docker for CRI Runtime.

After I installed the cluster, I deployed minio pod and exposed it as a NodePort.
The pod got deployed in the worker node (`10.72.12.52`) and my master node IP is `10.72.12.51`).
For the first two hours, I am able to access the login page via all three IPs (`10.72.12.51:30981`, `10.72.12.52:30981`, `10.72.13.53:30981`). However, after two hours, I lost access to the service via `10.72.12.51:30981` and `10.72.13.53:30981`. Now I am only able to access the service from the node on which it is running (`10.72.12.52`).

I have disabled the firewall and added `calico.conf` file inside `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` with the following content:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:cali*;interface-name:tunl*;interface-name:vxlan.calico
```

What am I missing in the setup that might cause this issue?

Comment: Hello @AbhinavSharma. It's hard to tell what could be the the issue here. Could you check if `kube-apiserver` is up and running?

Comment: yes, all the kube-system pods are up and running without any errors.

Comment: calicoctl get nodes and kubectl get nodes also show all three nodes in established and ready state

Comment: Hi @AbhinavSharma. Thanks for your responses. Could you also share which exact error you got when you lost the access to your service?

Comment: I am unable to pinpoint an error, I have checked logs of all kube-system pods (api-server, kube-proxy, calico-node). But they didn't gave any related error logs.

Comment: I have also checked that the firewall is disabled.

Comment: I was able to get the expected result when I switched to flannel cni.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As mentioned by @AbhinavSharma the problem was solved by switching from Calico to Flannel CNI.

More information regarding Flannel itself can be found [here](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel).